# Tabs are not working in dialog in dm-script

Tags: tabs, dialog, dm-script

Why do tabs not show up in dm script in dialogs?

---

When I create a simple dialog with three tabs (and a table layout) the tabs do not show up. The following dialog shows up:

[image: Dialog without tabs]

What I am expecting is something like this:

[image: Expected Dialog]

I used the following example code:

```c
class TestDialog : UIFrame{
    TagGroup createContent(object self){
        number total_length = 3
        TagGroup tabs = DLGCreateTabList(total_length);

        for(number i = 0; i < total_length; i++){
            TagGroup content = DLGCreateGroup();
            content.DLGLayout(DLGCreateTableLayout(3, 1, 0));

            TagGroup l = DLGCreateLabel("Row 1 of tab " + (i + 1));
            content.DLGAddElement(l);

            TagGroup v = DLGCreateLabel("Row 2 of tab " + (i + 1));
            content.DLGAddElement(v);

            TagGroup c = DLGCreateCheckBox("Checkbox of tab " + (i + 1));
            content.DLGAddElement(c);

            TagGroup tab = tabs.DLGAddTab("Tab " + (i + 1));
            tab.DLGAddElement(content);
        }

        return tabs;
    }

    object init(object self){
        return self.super.init(self.createContent())
    }
}

object dialog = alloc(TestDialog).Init();
dialog.pose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it out. It seems like adding a tab list as the direct child of a dialog does not work. There needs to be a **group around the tabs list**.

[image: Dialog with tabs]

```c
class TestDialog : UIFrame{
    TagGroup createContent(object self){
        number total_length = 3
        TagGroup tabs = DLGCreateTabList(total_length);

        for(number i = 0; i < total_length; i++){
            TagGroup content = DLGCreateGroup();

            // ...

            TagGroup tab = tabs.DLGAddTab("Tab " + (i + 1));
            tab.DLGAddElement(content);
        }

        // this is the important part
        TagGroup wrapper = DLGCreateGroup();
        wrapper.DLGAddElement(tabs);

        return wrapper;
    }

    object init(object self){
        return self.super.init(self.createContent())
    }
}

object dialog = alloc(TestDialog).Init();
dialog.pose();
```

Comment: Correct. Seems you're building a nice repository of dialog Q&A all by yourself here. It *will* be useful for others, though :c)

Comment: General hint: Dialog-building is just TagGroup building. It sometimes helps to show the final dialog taggroup using `TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow()`.

Comment: @BmyGuest Creating a help for others in the future is my only excuse. I already feel guilty for spamming the [dm-script] questions :D

Comment: Don't. I think it's actually very helpful, as long as you keep both Q and A in a style that allows for easy Googling issues it *will* be helpful. Hope you soon reach the karma threshold to accept your own answers. Always nicer to have issues closed.

Comment: @BmyGuest Thank you. I will go on :) I have to wait two more days, then I can mark it as solved. It's true, it's annoying to have open questions that are in fact solved.